# Trouble shooting abs/esp light on Peugeot 308

Tags: obd-ii, brake-rotor, abs, dtc, peugeot-308

I have just replaced the rear discs on a Peugeot 308 hatchback, 2010 model. After this, the abs and esp fault warnings were displayed on the console, and abs/esp lights came on. Plugging in an OBD scanner I got the following DTC

C1326 - Status: Test is inhibited by other DTC, Validated and stored in non volatile memory.

I can't find this fault code in the Peugeot fault code lists I'm looking at.

When fitting the new discs, there was considerable rust around both abs sensors preventing them from sitting flat, I cleared this up and refitted the sensors. I have checked both sensors for continuity, both reading approximately 460Ohms, I do not have a scope to test the reluctor rings. Both sensors are less than 1mm from the reluctor ring cover, brake fluid is at maximum.

I was under the impression that if an abs fault occurred the cruise control would stop working, mine works, the speedo too. I was wondering if this could help to narrow down the problem?

**Update**

I have checked the signal from the abs sensor on a multimeter scope shown in the image
[image: ABS Signal]

the flat part shown in the image occurs when the wheel is still spinning and is periodic. This implies to me that the reluctor ring was damaged when I fitted the new discs.

Comment: Are the ABS sensors two wire or three wires? If two wires, these are very much typical Hall Effect sensors. You can easily check them by putting a multimeter on DC with the leads on each wire, then waving a metal wand (like a wrench) over the sensor and seeing if it registers.

Comment: Call auto stores (Autozone) and check if they perform free reading of error codes for ABS. Mention your model and year. As a rule, abs uses a separate module and stores error codes there, apart from engine and other modules. Either a Peugeot or aftermarket reader can decode ABS errors. However, many don't so check around. Brake shops may have better readers. ABS errors; each wheel speed sensor, abs unit, solenoid valves, etc. Exposed parts affected by weathering; wiring to each wheel sensor, sensor, reluctor damage.

Comment: I measured the signal directly from the sensor on a scope and updated the post.